# Attributing user id from current user session from an importing csv function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, import, userid

I have an import function that lets my user import data with CSV file. It works but I want to have their user_id attributed to the data they import

Here is the code, the import function :

```
def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

  product_hash = row.to_hash
  Product.create!(product_hash)

end # end CSV.foreach
```

The product.create from the controller :

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.set_user!(current_user)
  @product.user_id = current_user.id
  @product.save
  respond_with(@product)
end
```

This does give the user id to the data when the user creates it manually but not when he creates data with a CSV five via the import function. I would like to attribute the user id when they import data with the CSV but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: `current_user.id` is the only id that you want to assign to every product based on your `create` method, correct? so All of the products will have the same `user_id` correct?

Comment: Yeah if say person A uploads a file with 100 products, I want those 100 products to have his user_id(id from person A). And if person B does the same I want his user_id to be attributed to the products(id from person B)

Answer (score 2):

The `Product.create!` is not using the `def create` that is defined in your controller. [Read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create) for further explanation.

I would pass the `current_user` to the `def self.import` from wherever its getting called. Then assign that `user` to the new `product` object you are creating. So suppose you pass `user` to your `def self.import` method, it will be something like:

`product = Product.new(product_hash)
 product.user = user
 product.save`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I personally don't like your approach and I can see the future flaws in it however in this instance here is my suggestion to keep things DRY and achieve what you need.

In your Model:

```
attr_accessor :product_user

def save_with_a_user
 set_user!(product_user)
 user_id = product_user.id
 save!
end
```

In your Controller now you can say

```
def create
  .....
  @product.product_user = current_user
  @product.save_with_a_user
  .....
end
```

Now in the other side of the scenario:

```
  def self.import(file, current_user)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      product_hash = row.to_hash
      @product = Product.new(product_hash)
      @product.product_user = current_user
      @product.save_with_a_user

    end # end CSV.foreach
  end
```

**YOU MUST REFACTOR THIS**

I have defined the instance variable over and over (Not a good idea, even if you are overriding it). Also I haven't tested this. Please use this as a guide.

Unfortunately you have to pass the `current_user` to the `import` this is the main reason I don't like your approach. ( Call me old fashioned ) I like to keep them separate. (do some investigations on Design Patterns).

Cheers

Comment: I agree with you @Mr H about passing the `current_user` to the `import`

Comment: code gets smelly when you see `current_user` starts popping up in models here and there. I myself guilty of this. The easy way to know you have a smelly code, just try to right a unit test for the `current_user` in the model. It is a pain in the neck. Cheers

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help!!  I tried with your method and modified the current user method with yours and it works well when I add a new value manually. However when I try to upload with a CSV I get the following error :  undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Class:0x0000000380cc50> and it points to the import function

Comment: @dogg you must pass the `current_user`  to the `def import` while u are calling it..

Comment: @dewdrops I'm sorry but I tried to google and did a lot of try but I couldn't get it to work well, I always end up with the current user being undefined local variable ... How do I need to pass it in the def import?

Comment: I'd like to see how you are invoking your `import` method. Can you update?

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
def import
    Product.import(params[:file], current_user)
    redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully imported.'
end
```

model:

```
def self.import(file, user)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
        product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
        product.attributes = row.to_hash
        product.user = user
        product.save!
end
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Which parts make the crucial difference to the original code?